# Finite Element, NASTRAN, DMAP, how to print the differential stiffness matrix in .f06 output file

Tags: optimization, finite-element, matrix

We are working on an optimization problem in which we can approximate the eigenvalue calculation by assuming a constant eigenvector, using the formula:

$$
\tilde{\lambda}=\frac{\{\phi_0\}^T[K]\{\phi_0\}}{\{\phi_0\}^T[K_{G_0}]\{\phi_0\}}
$$

where $\{\phi_0\}$ is the already calculated eigenvector, $[K_{G_0}]$ is the already calculated differential stiffness matrix and $[K]$ is the new stiffness matrix.
We managed already to print $[K]$ using a couple of DMAP commands ([see example in this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ms7xj4xp06qa5f/finite-element-nastran-how-to-print-the-differential-stiffness-matrix-in-f06.zip)), but how to print $[K_{G_0}]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scrutinizing thoroughly the NASTRAN documentation I found the following option to print the stiffness matrix $[K]$:

```
SOL 101
TIME 20
DIAG 8
compile semg
alter 'kjjz.*stiffness' 
matprn kjjz//
CEND
SPC = 1
LOAD = 1
SUBCASE 1
BEGIN BULK
INCLUDE 'bulk_data.dat'
```

That will print the stiffness matrix into the `.f06` file.

After printing the stiffness matrix the differential stiffness matrix can be calculated using the approximation above, i.e. dividing the stiffness matrix by the eigenmode:

$$[K_{G_0}] = \frac{[K]}{\lambda_0}$$

Where  $\lambda_0$ is the already computed eigenvalue (using SOL 105 for example). There will be a different $[K_{G_0}]$ for each eigenvalue.

[A sample code is available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ms7xj4xp06qa5f/finite-element-nastran-how-to-print-the-differential-stiffness-matrix-in-f06.zip) using a Python script to compute the approximated eigenvalue using the equation presented in the question. You have to execute:

```
python test_01.py
```

Things to be improved here:

- how to stop the solution just after the stiffness matrix is printed, to avoid running the SOL 101 (but running it with zero load will be fast)
- how to print the stiffness matrix in a binary file